# Open source software for car navigation on iOS platform

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations, spatialite, ios

I'm trying to make a car offline navigation app for iOS. Now I analyze OpenStreetMap features what to use. I would like to know if there is open source solution for the following parts of app:

- Best storing of geodata - do you know Spatialite? Or use standard file system?
- Rendering OSM (whatever format/own?) - vector rendering, not tile's system
- Routing OSM, finding shortest/fastest path

I did some experiments but if you have any experiences, I will be glad if you help me with start.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for [Navit software](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Navit) which is an open source car navigation software capable of using OSM data.

Answer (score -1):

[RoutingKit](https://github.com/RoutingKit/RoutingKit) will do what you want. It's in C++, so it can be integrated into an iOS app by calling it from Objective C++. It can import OpenStreetMap data.

It's open source with a permissive license.